# What is a possible side reaction during the oxidation of fluorene?

Tags: organic-chemistry

What is a possible side reaction during the oxidation of fluorene? 9-fluorenone is synthesized, but what else?

Comment: This is a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/) question. We ‎have a policy which states that you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the ‎problem. It'll make us certain that we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this ‎question may get closed.‎